# export 'catchError' was not found in 'rxjs' when tsconfig.json target is ES2020 in angular 14

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular14, ecmascript-2020, angular14upgrade

I have updated my angular library project to angular 14 and while and building my app I am getting
following Error

**Command**

```
ng build --base-href /home/ --configuration production
```

**ERROR:**

```
/node_modules/@rcis/common/fesm2020/rcis-common.mjs:2000:39-51 - Error: export 'catchError' (imported as 'catchError$1') was not found in 'rxjs'
```

and when I change the target in *tsconfig.json* from **ES2020** to **ES2015** it works fine.

**tsconfig.json code -**

```
     {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES2020", //if I change ES2015 it works fine
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

What I need to make the change in order to work **catchError** with ES2020 in angular 14.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is your version of `rxjs`?

Comment: I am using "rxjs": "^7.5.7",

Comment: More importantly, what is @rcis?

Comment: Like you can see its inside /node_modules/ @rcis/common is my custom angular library which is also the same angular version 14 alike my angular application